# Step-by-step guide for running PHP/MySQL on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, mysql, iis-7.5

Any complete guide for setting/running PHP/MySQL on IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up MySQL should be pretty easy - run through the windows installer and it should be painless.

Setting up PHP correctly in IIS is another matter though.  I found [this guide](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-7/) to be extremely helpful.

You can use the web platform installer for PHP to get up and running quickly, but my experience has been that it falls seriously short, especially if you need to support multiple PHP versions or different php.ini settings for different sites.

Answer (score 1):

A plugin to setup PHP in IIS: http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/